# Button not passing a period "." as string to EditText object

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i'm starting out with Android dev and i have a problem I can't seem to get my head around.
Im building a calculator obviously utilising a range of buttons. I can  get the other buttons to post their corresponding numbers in the EditText just fine, but the dot/period simply wont appear even though it is almost identical in almost every way and linked up in the same manner in the Java code. My code is below: I have shown the XML for button number 9 and then the decimal button to show their similarity

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:text="9"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:text="."
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0" />
```

And the Java to initialise and use them is as follows

```
private EditText newNumber;
private EditText baseNumber;
private TextView operation;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        baseNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.baseNumber);
        newNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newNumber);
        operation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.operation);

        Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button buttonDot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDot);

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button b = (Button) v;
                newNumber.append(b.getText().toString());
            }
        };

        button9.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonDot.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

I've taken out alot of the other buttons so to not have an extensive list. Simply showing a button that seems to work - button9, and one that doesn't - buttonDot, despite being created and initialised almost identically.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your EditText in xml:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
```

If it doesn't have numberDecimal then it will not allow you to enter decimal numbers.